# Storing a device-context in a member variable instead of getting/releasing it on every execution of OnPaint

Tags: winapi, mfc, gdi

I have a dialog class which stores a window object:

```
class CInputDlg : public CDialog
{

...

private:
    CWnd m_cImageWindow;

...

};
```

In the dialog class `OnPaint` routine, I draw into the window object:

```
void CInputDlg::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);

    if (IsIconic())
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        CDC* pDC = m_cImageWindow.GetDC();
        CDC  cDC;
        cDC.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);

        cDC.SelectObject(m_hImageBitmap);
        pDC->StretchBlt(...,...,...,...,&cDC,...,...,...,...,SRCCOPY);

        cDC.DeleteDC();
        m_cImageWindow.ReleaseDC(pDC);
    }
}
```

Instead of getting/releasing and creating/deleting those two device contexts **on every execution** of the `OnPaint` routine, I would like to store them as member variables of the dialog class, and initialize them **once** in the `OnInitDialog` routine.

But [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183571(v=vs.85).aspx) says that "an application obtains a display DC only when it must draw in the client area, and when the application is finished drawing, it must release the DC".

I have also read somewhere that when a process allocates a DC, it affects other processes in the system, since there is a limit number of DCs that can be acquired simultaneously.

So my questions is:

1. Is it safe to go along with my desired scheme?
2. Is it appropriate to go along with my desired scheme?
3. Trying my desired scheme, *Visual Leak Detector* says 'No memory leaks detected' even without calling `DeleteDC` and `ReleaseDC`. Can I assume that this happens automatically during the destruction of the corresponding instances?

Thank you.

Comment: you need create compatible *DC* in memory only once, but not on every paint. and save it. when you handle `WP_PAINT` you need anyway call `BeginPaint` direct or indirect. and this call return you display *DC* for window. so - not save display *DC* but create once and save compatible DC and on paint simply copy compatible *DC* to display by *BitBlt*

Comment: and *Visual Leak Detector* detects leak only in *heap* it not detect GDI object leaks

Comment: @RbMm: For your first comment: If I cannot call `m_pDC = m_cImageWindow.GetDC()` once, then I cannot call m_cDC.CreateCompatibleDC(m_pDC)` once either. If I understand correctly, then you suggest to do the latter once but do the former on every execution of `OnPaint`.

Comment: @RbMm: For your second comment: Why should I care about any other leaks? Wouldn't those be gone anyway as soon as every instance in the application is destroyed?

Comment: If that is your only concern, then you shouldn't care about memory leaks either. Those are also gone, once the process is terminated.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I just consider heap-leaks more severe, cause they tend to affect the program during execution. But thinking it over, so would GDI leaks...

Comment: you can call `CreateCompatibleDC(0)`. and of course need create compatible *DC* once and save it. or use it loss any sense - why not draw to display *DC* direct ? what you doing now(create compatible *DC* on every paint) absolute senseless and bad for performance. and look like you absolute nothing understand about memory leaks. *VLD* hook heap allocation/free. and report abot this kind of leaks only. this tool not spy to GDI objects and can not detect are thay leaked

Comment: Memory leaks are local to the application. They waste address space, which isn't all that severe especially with 64-bit applications. GDI resources on the other hand are [limited per user session](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2010/03/31/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-user-and-gdi-objects-part-2/). A GDI leak in one application can cause another application to fail.

Comment: @RbMm: Leaks are not the main issue I'm concerned with. With regards to `CreateCompatibleDC`, I need to create a DC compatible with the window object's DC. "why not draw to display DC direct" - because I need to load a bitmap, clip a certain rectangle in it and stretch it into different dimensions. Notice the call to `StretchBlt`.

Comment: @IInspectable: Missing out a couple of heap-deallocations has caused my process to run out of memory space. So "isn't all that severe especially with 64-bit applications" is a program-dependent statement (or in other words, generally wrong).

Comment: you need call `CreateCompatibleDC` once at `WM_CREATE` or `WM_ININITDIALOG` and this time you can get *DC* from your window. if it on screen window - `CreateCompatibleDC(0)` will be have the same effect. -*creates a memory DC compatible with the application's current screen* and you save this *DC* usually util `WM_DESTROY` . save the display *DC* no sense because you any way get it when call `BeginPaint` and you must call this function on paint

Comment: *"So 'isn't all that severe especially with 64-bit applications' is a program-dependent statement (or in other words, generally wrong)"* - No, that statement is correct. The severity of a process, that only harms itself is a **lot** lower than the severity of a process that can harm every other process in the same user session.

Comment: @RbMm: Note that I am using `m_cImageWindow.GetDC()`, and not `this->GetDC()`.

Comment: @IInspectable: OK, thank you.

Comment: i don't know what is your object `m_cImageWindow` but think it *DC* compatible with current screen. so simply use `CreateCompatibleDC(0)` when you window created. or when you create your `m_cImageWindow` and get it *DC* and call with it `CreateCompatibleDC` in what problem at all ?

Comment: @RbMm: Well, that is **exactly** what my question is all about - Can I use a member variable `CDC* m_pDC` and initialize it **only once**, by setting `m_pDC = m_cImageWindow.GetDC()` immediately after I create the window object (i.e., inside the `OnInitDialog` function, after calling `m_cImageWindow.CreateEx(...)` )?

Comment: @goodvibration - ok, look like you nothing understand

Comment: I'm assuming, this is a case of premature optimization. Creating a device context is a fairly cheap operation. The (more) expensive operation is creation of a backing bitmap, but you don't appear to be using one anyway. I'd recommend going the standard route and creating the `CPaintDC` for every `OnPaint` invocation. Have you profiled, that this poses a bottleneck for your application? (And why aren't you using the `CPaintDC` anyway?)

Comment: @RbMm: Yes, OK, I "nothing understand". Great answer, thank you.

Comment: @IInspectable: Because I haven't been able to use it in order to "`StretchBlt`" my bitmap image successfully. I believe that this is because the `CPaintDC` instance belongs to `this`, while I need to draw the image inside `m_cImageWindow`.

Comment: No one has yet confused the issue by pointing out that there is a class style: CS_OWNDC where you can state up front that you would like a single DC associated with the window for its life.

Comment: can note at all that `WM_PAINT` arrived to one window `CInputDlg` but code paint to another window - `m_cImageWindow`. every time recreate in memory DC - absolute senseless. need paint to window which receive `WM_PAINT` but not to another. and window DC we always got form `PAINTSTRUCT` anyway

Comment: @RbMm: I'm sorry, but your English is "absolute senseless".

Comment: @ChrisBecke: Thank you. I've been considering this option, but the MSDN says that it's a single DC associated with the class, so I wasn't quite sure what was meant by that. I mean, I have a `CWnd` instance. Does this mean that it will hold a unique DC, or that the entire `CWnd` class (i.e., every `CWnd` instance) will get the same DC?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060601-06/?p=31003

Comment: @ChrisBecke: Thank you!!! This is an awesome explanation, and essentially an answer to my question! Thanks again :)